# How to hang a projector screen (cloth) with a few inches away from the wall?

Tags: hanging, anchor, screens, mount, projector

I have some odd fixture/design on the dry wall I want to hang the projector screen against, but if I were to fasten the screen on that wall, the crooked things on the wall will bulge through the screen causing breaks and distort the image.

Are there some sort of anchors that can extend an object away from the wall? I hope i'm making sense. Here's a scratch of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would fasten a "furring strip" (a piece of perhaps 2x2) to the wall at the top of the screen. Make it the same width as the screen, but screw it into the studs inside the wall (NOT just into the drywall sheet-rock)  Then hang the screen from that.

I would paint the strip black before installation to minimize visual interference. Depending on what kind of screen you are talking about (not disclosed?) you could put another identical strip at the bottom and actually STRETCH the screen fabric between the top "rail" and the bottom "rail". That would keep it nice and tight and wrinkle-free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing anchors into drywall, extended in the manner you've sketched, the leverage provided by the screen will likely force the anchor free of the wall.

Consider to add a spacer block with some surface area between the wall and the screen. The anchors would be used to secure the block, perhaps more than one if needed, and you can attach the screen to the block.

A larger spacer block will allow more anchors to improve the fastening, while giving you the clearance you require from the wall.